# SSH fork of unprivileged child failed on connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

we have some problem when we try to make an ssh connection to our server.

When we connect with user X (ssh x@serverIP) we receive these errors on console:

```
Connection to serverIP closed by remote host.
Connection to serverIP closed.
```

In the same time on /var/log/auth.log on server we can find these errors:

```
Nov  2 09:27:02 dbtde02 sshd[21556]: Accepted password for X from serverIP port 41505 ssh2
Nov  2 09:27:02 dbtde02 sshd[21556]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user X by (uid=0)
Nov  2 09:27:02 dbtde02 systemd-logind[1028]: New session 1559 of user X.
Nov  2 09:27:02 dbtde02 sshd[21556]: fatal: fork of unprivileged child failed
Nov  2 09:27:02 dbtde02 systemd-logind[1028]: Removed session 1559.
```

If we restart sshd service this problem persists. The only way to make it work is to restart the server.

If we connect to this server with root user we don't have any problem.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: do you have enough free memory on your server?

Comment: @Jakuje yes we have.

Comment: Seems like a resource exhaustion of some kind, f.e. maximum number of procces reached. Do you have console access (not ssh) when this happens?

Comment: It sounds like you have run out of processes. Last few processes are reserved for root only, which would explain why you can still log in as root. If you type `cat /proc/loadavg` you should see how many are running on the system. And if you type `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` you should see the system-wide limit.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks you for this response.I will try it when the problem come back

Comment: I can reproduce the issue reliably by running: `seq 100000 | parallel -j300 -q ssh lo echo -n '" "'`

Comment: It is a permission problem in my case (sshd in Win10, started by user), as the previous log message states: `sshd: error: CreateProcessAsUserW failed error:1314`